# probability that a year has 53 mondays

Tags: probability, problem-solving

We have the years from 2001, 2002, 2003,... to 2010. Say, a year is chosen at random from the listed years. What is the probability that the chosen year has 53 Mondays ?

Comment: How many of those years have 53 mondays? Count 'em up!

Comment: Well, only 2002 and 2008 had 53 Mondays. That's 2 years out of 10. So if you choose at random one year out of 2001..2010, what's the probability to hit either 2002 or 2008?

Answer (score 1):

In $400$ years (a Gregorian calendar cycle) there are $365\times 303+366\times 97 =146097$ days which is $\frac{146097}{7}=20871$ weeks and so there are $20871$ Mondays.

Since $20871=329\times 52+71\times 53$, there are $71$ years with $53$ Mondays, and so the probability that a year has $53$ Mondays is $\frac{71}{400}=0.1775$.

Similar calculations over a $400$ year cycle can show that the $13$th of a month is more likely to be a Friday than another other particular day.

Comment: The question specifies that the year is between 2001 and 2010.

Comment: @MJD: True, but less interesting.

Comment: Also, Friday 13 and Wednesday 13 are equiprobable.

Comment: @MJD: Friday $13$th: $688$ times in $400$ years. Wednesday $13$th: $687$ times in $400$ years

Comment: You're correct, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

A year with 53 Mondays must start on a Monday, or be a leap year starting on a Sunday, on average a given year having 53 Mondays occurs about once every five or six years (five times in a period of twenty-eight years).

Since 2000 and going up to 2050, the following years have 53 Mondays:

2001
2007
2012 (LY)
2018
2024 (LY)
2029
2035
2040 (LY)
2046

LY = Leap Year